# Chakra UI Non-linear Stepper customization

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

When using the Stepper component in Chakra UI, how can I navigate forward without marking the previous steps as complete? (Similar to the Material UI non-linear stepper.)
In the code snippet below, if you move the active step forward by increasing the `index` prop in the `Stepper`, the previous steps are marked as complete:

```
<Stepper index={1} orientation="vertical" height="400px" gap="0">
      {steps.map((step, index) => (
        <Step key={index}>
          <StepIndicator>
            <StepStatus
              complete={<StepIcon />}
              incomplete={<StepNumber />}
              active={<StepNumber />}
            />
          </StepIndicator>

          <Box flexShrink="0">
            <StepTitle>{step.title}</StepTitle>
            <StepDescription>{step.description}</StepDescription>
          </Box>

          <StepSeparator />
        </Step>
      ))}
    </Stepper>
```